# group by prioritize color

Tags: mysql

Say I have a database filled with students and I wish to group by gender but default the color shirt returned so that if a student is wearing blue it will default blue over any other color. Likewise make it so that Orange is only shown as a last resort?

`select shirt_color, gender from students group by gender`

If I wanted to show the oldest student age I would write something like this:

`select max(age), gender from students group by gender`

If there are only 4 shirt colors: Red, Blue, Green, and Orange. How would I go about returning a result that would only show Orange as a last resort?

My thoughts are something along these lines:

`select color, gender from (select * from students order by color NOT LIKE "%Orange%', color) group by gender`

Students Table

```
M - Orange
M - Blue
F - Red
F - Orange
M - Green
```

Desired Results

```
M - Blue -> or Green
F - Red
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: @Mureinik two samples were giving in the question. I am trying to get a result that will only use a specific color as a last resort

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Tough question, I don't know if that functionality exists. You may just have to write a separate sql statement and replace the data you return. For those who are curious, the OP is asking if there is essentially a MAX()  function but instead of an integer they want a varchar sortable. I think you had the right idea with CASE WHEN color NOT LIKE '%Orange%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, color. But that just gets overwritten by group by. Best of luck though

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
SELECT color, gender FROM students WHERE color = 'Orange' GROUP BY gender
```

But to be honest, it's gard to understand what do you want to do exactly (if my answer is wrong)

Comment: The object is to prevent Orange from showing up at all costs. You couldn't simply write `where color != 'Orange'` because if the only result that returns is Orange, then that color needs to be shown. But thank you for trying

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured it out...

```
Select gender, color from students s where color = (select color from students c where s.gender = c.gender order by case  when color not like '%Orange%' then 1 else 2 end color limit 0, 1) order by gender asc
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that... And you can't wrap the subquery in a subquery to avoid the issue because you need to reference the outer select statement from the inner.